# ACF order relationship by date

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, order

Hi I am trying to sort a relationship in ACF by date, this is the code I have so far but $the_query is returning empty.

```
- $journalEntries = get_field('author', false, false)
- $args = array('post__in' => $journalEntries,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
  )
- $the_query = new WP_Query($args)

- if ( $the_query->have_posts() )
  - $dataLink == 1 ? $active="active" : $active=""
  .tab-link.tab-container.journal(data-tab-link="#{$dataLink}" class="#{$active}")
    .tab-content                
      %ul
        - while ( $the_query->have_posts() )
          - $the_query->the_post()
          %li.stagger
            %a(href="#{get_the_permalink()}")
              - echo get_the_title()
  - $dataLink++
  - wp_reset_query()
```

This is what var_dump($the_query) returns:

```
object(WP_Query)[2490]
  public 'query' => 
    array (size=3)
      'post__in' => 
        array (size=9)
          0 => int 2687
          1 => int 2691
          2 => int 2693
          3 => int 2695
          4 => int 2697
          5 => int 2700
          6 => int 2703
          7 => int 2789
          8 => int 2791
      'orderby' => string 'date' (length=4)
      'order' => string 'DESC' (length=4)
  public 'query_vars' => 
    array (size=65)
      'post__in' => 
        array (size=9)
          0 => int 2687
          1 => int 2691
          2 => int 2693
          3 => int 2695
          4 => int 2697
          5 => int 2700
          6 => int 2703
          7 => int 2789
          8 => int 2791
      'orderby' => string 'date' (length=4)
      'order' => string 'DESC' (length=4)
      'error' => string '' (length=0)
      'm' => string '' (length=0)
      'p' => int 0
      'post_parent' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment_id' => int 0
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'static' => string '' (length=0)
      'pagename' => string '' (length=0)
      'page_id' => int 0
      'second' => string '' (length=0)
      'minute' => string '' (length=0)
      'hour' => string '' (length=0)
      'day' => int 0
      'monthnum' => int 0
      'year' => int 0
      'w' => int 0
      'category_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag' => string '' (length=0)
      'cat' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'author' => string '' (length=0)
      'author_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'feed' => string '' (length=0)
      'tb' => string '' (length=0)
      'paged' => int 0
      'meta_key' => string '' (length=0)
      'meta_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'preview' => string '' (length=0)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
      'sentence' => string '' (length=0)
      'title' => string '' (length=0)
      'fields' => string '' (length=0)
      'menu_order' => string '' (length=0)
      'embed' => string '' (length=0)
      'category__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_name__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => boolean false
      'suppress_filters' => boolean false
      'cache_results' => boolean true
      'update_post_term_cache' => boolean true
      'lazy_load_term_meta' => boolean true
      'update_post_meta_cache' => boolean true
      'post_type' => string '' (length=0)
      'posts_per_page' => int 10
      'nopaging' => boolean false
      'comments_per_page' => string '50' (length=2)
      'no_found_rows' => boolean false
  public 'tax_query' => 
    object(WP_Tax_Query)[2514]
      public 'queries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
      protected 'table_aliases' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'queried_terms' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'primary_table' => string 'wp_posts' (length=8)
      public 'primary_id_column' => string 'ID' (length=2)
  public 'meta_query' => 
    object(WP_Meta_Query)[2513]
      public 'queries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'relation' => null
      public 'meta_table' => null
      public 'meta_id_column' => null
      public 'primary_table' => null
      public 'primary_id_column' => null
      protected 'table_aliases' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'clauses' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'has_or_relation' => boolean false
  public 'date_query' => boolean false
  public 'request' => string 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID IN (2687,2691,2693,2695,2697,2700,2703,2789,2791) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10' (length=325)
  public 'posts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'post_count' => int 0
  public 'current_post' => int -1
  public 'in_the_loop' => boolean false
  public 'comment_count' => int 0
  public 'current_comment' => int -1
  public 'found_posts' => int 0
  public 'max_num_pages' => int 0
  public 'max_num_comment_pages' => int 0
  public 'is_single' => boolean false
  public 'is_preview' => boolean false
  public 'is_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_archive' => boolean false
  public 'is_date' => boolean false
  public 'is_year' => boolean false
  public 'is_month' => boolean false
  public 'is_day' => boolean false
  public 'is_time' => boolean false
  public 'is_author' => boolean false
  public 'is_category' => boolean false
  public 'is_tag' => boolean false
  public 'is_tax' => boolean false
  public 'is_search' => boolean false
  public 'is_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_comment_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_trackback' => boolean false
  public 'is_home' => boolean true
  public 'is_404' => boolean false
  public 'is_embed' => boolean false
  public 'is_paged' => boolean false
  public 'is_admin' => boolean false
  public 'is_attachment' => boolean false
  public 'is_singular' => boolean false
  public 'is_robots' => boolean false
  public 'is_posts_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_post_type_archive' => boolean false
  private 'query_vars_hash' => string '2ea1348ad53c0c8955b5eb02c6700ffb' (length=32)
  private 'query_vars_changed' => boolean false
  public 'thumbnails_cached' => boolean false
  private 'stopwords' => null
  private 'compat_fields' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'query_vars_hash' (length=15)
      1 => string 'query_vars_changed' (length=18)
  private 'compat_methods' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'init_query_flags' (length=16)
      1 => string 'parse_tax_query' (length=15)
```

I also tried editing functions.php with this but it didn't seem to work:

```
function my_post_object_query( $args, $field, $post )
{
    // modify the order
    $args['orderby'] = 'date';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';

    return $args;
}

// filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/name=author', 'my_post_object_query', 10, 3);
```

Comment: The $journalEntries IDs are a post_type = post? Because if you don't specify the post_type in the WP_Query it will default to 'post'.

Comment: OMG you are right! I thought the post type was post or news (tried both) but it was actually "journal", thanks!

Comment: Yep. No problem, have made this same mistake a few times myself. I will post my comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $journalEntries IDs are a post_type = post? Because if you don't specify the post_type in the WP_Query it will default to 'post'.

So your $args array should be:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'put_post_type_here',
    'post__in' => $journalEntries,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
```